# Every time a user logins in they are automatically blocked

Tags: login, security

Every time a user logs in they are automatically blocked.  When I enable them again they login once and it disables them again.

It's making it impossible for my staff to get any work done.  It's occurring on multiple sites.

Comment: When you conducted your investigation, did you find anything peculiar to report to us?

Comment: That's not Joomla core behavior. What non-core extensions do you use? Do you use Akeeba Admin Tools or any other security related extension?

Comment: Yes Admin Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the Litespeed cache plugin https://github.com/litespeedtech/lscache-joomla/issues/42

Answer (score 1):

With Admintools it keeps a history of banned IP's as well as the currently banned IP's. If you check the `#__admintools_ipbanhistory` table via phpMyadmin or whatever you use you will probably see the people or their IP's listed. I have found clearing this table of the entries has solved a similar issue that I have had in the past.